# SSH Error: Could not save the page: Content HTML contains restricted elements. Allowed HTML attributes for tag

Tags: magento2.4, ssh

does anyone have any information or details on the following warning that I am seeing in the 2.4.3 when I try to run bin/magento magesetup:setup:run with Argument:

> Could not save the page: Content HTML contains restricted elements. Allowed HTML attributes for tag "a" are: class,width,height,style,alt,title,border,id,data-active-tab,data-appearance,data-autoplay,data-autoplay-speed,data-background-images,data-background-type,data-carousel-mode,data-center-padding,data-content-type,data-element,data-enable-parallax,data-fade,data-grid-size,data-infinite-loop,data-link-type,data-locations,data-overlay-color,data-parallax-speed,data-pb-style,data-same-width,data-show-arrows,data-show-button,data-show-controls,data-show-dots,data-show-overlay,data-slide-name,data-slick-index,data-role,data-product-id,data-price-box,aria-hidden,data-tab-name,data-video-fallback-src,data-video-lazy-load,data-video-loop,data-video-overlay-color,data-video-play-only-visible,data-video-src,href,role,target,tabindex,rel

I can't find what is the Problem and how to fix it, please help. The WYSIWYG editor is disabled from Backend

Answer (score 0):

After apply '`bin/magento cms:wysiwyg:restrict n`'  command my 2.4.3 allow to save editing cms page and blocks (but warnitg is present even though I have overridden class `Magento\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Validator`    https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/350710/85907)